# No mic input in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, microphone

I had this problem, where my speaker audio was showing "Dummy Output". I searched online and found this command worked for many users:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

It worked for me, and the speaker output was back again, but now my microphone does not seem to work. I tried both internal mic of laptop and headset mic, but nothing's working. I also tried online voice recorders, but all of them said that "Microphone not detected". I have also attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krhf1.jpg) of my audio input settings.

Please help me solve this problem, as I am working from home and have regular meetings.